# Draw points connected by spiral on a sphere with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw a sphere with points on its surface using Matplotlib. These points shall be connected by a spiral that spirals from one side of the sphere to the other. 
To clarify this a little bit the plot should more or less look like this: [image: Sphere with points and spiral]
Has anyone a tip about how to do this?

Comment: As I understand it, matplotlib doesn't have true 3D plotting, so it may be unable to automatically remove the parts of the "dots" that fall inside the sphere or are obstructed by it. Rather than writing your own code to do this, you might try mayavi, which is natively 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Need to know parameters of spiral, formula or set of points.

However I post a code to plot a line with markers on a sphere for your start:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = 1 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 1 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 1 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
elev = 10.
rot = 80. / 180. * np.pi
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=1, cstride=1, color='y', linewidth=0, alpha=0.5)

# plot lines in spherical coordinates system
a = np.array([-np.sin(elev / 180 * np.pi), 0, np.cos(elev / 180 * np.pi)])
b = np.array([0, 1, 0])
b = b * np.cos(rot) + np.cross(a, b) * np.sin(rot) + a * np.dot(a, b) * (1 - np.cos(rot))
ax.plot(np.sin(u),np.cos(u),0,color='r', linestyle = '-', marker='o', linewidth=2.5)

ax.view_init(elev = elev, azim = 0)
plt.show()
```

[image]